# inserting data from one mysql table into another mysql table using a form

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm still very new in mysql scripting and I need help on the above matter.

I have two table consist of same field names except one field as below:

### table 1

```
id_student, studentname, studentnric, studentno, dateofbirth, address, phone, courses, session
```

### table 2

```
id_graduate, studentname, studentnric, studentno, courses, session
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, to get the data in the first table into the second table

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT id_student as id_graduate, studentname, studentnric, studentno, courses, session 
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at insert into select

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html